# Trigger to rerun SQL query when table is updated

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Suppose I have 3 tables A,B,C and a table, D, such that D is created from the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a,col_b FROM A WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a,col_b FROM B WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a,col_b FROM C WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL
```

I want D to be updated whenever any of tables A,B,or C are inserted into. I'm thinking I would use a trigger to do that, but I can't find anything online about how to rerun queries on an insert trigger.

The reason I want to do this is because it is a subquery in a larger query and this subquery really bogs down the query time. I'm hoping that by storing it in a table that regularly updates itself will speed up the query an acceptable amount.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` without `ORDER BY` is . . . well troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a **view** would be the straightforward method such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW D AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a, col_b FROM A WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a, col_b FROM B WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) col_a, col_b FROM C WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0e59641df6cefa79328b5764ab639f3e)</kbd>

Comment: This is a good idea, however, the reason I want to have it stored in a table (D) is because I currently have this query (the one in my question) as a sub-query and it really bogs down the runtime. I was aiming to speed up the query by having this data previously stored in it's own table, and that's why I'm not sure a view would work for this situation.

Comment: You can use a materialized view and `REFRESH` it in an `AFTER` trigger. But if you run that query on every update, the cure is probably worse than the disease.